# Fit an img in a non fixed dimension container

Tags: html, css

I've got issues because I can't "auto-resize" an img in the div where I've put it, I'm doing this and it doesn't work:

```
#slider img{
position:relative; 
border:none;
display:none;
height: 100%; width: 100%;}

#slider { 
background:#fff url(loading.gif) no-repeat 50% 50%;
margin-left: 10%;
margin-right: 15%;
position:absolute;
 width:75%;height:50%;
transform: translate3d(0,0,0);
box-shadow: 0px 1px 5px #999999;}

 <div id="slider">

      <img src="SAM_3142.JPG"border=0 />
</div>
```

So I want the img to fit perfectly in this div regardless of the div's dimensions, do you know how to do so please?

Comment: Add the image as a background image and apply size properties. `background-size: cover;`

Answer (score 0):

No need to add `position: relative;` and `position: absolute;` in that case:

```
#slider img{
 width: 100%;
}

#slider { 
background:#fff url(loading.gif) no-repeat 50% 50%;
margin-left: 10%;
margin-right: 15%;
 width:75%;
box-shadow: 0px 1px 5px #999999;}
```

[See it here](https://jsfiddle.net/0363t6pk/)

**EDIT**

By default `img` tag in inline type so you have a small gap under the `img` caused by the default `vertical-align` property which is `baseline`.

If you change it to `vertical-align: top;`, no more gaps :)

[See it here](https://jsfiddle.net/0363t6pk/4/)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Unfortunately it works(i tested your method in an test file), but not in my file.php , it keeps cutting my images to fit (partly) in the div. Maybe it's because the div is actually a slider, and the .js file involved to make the img "slide" is the problem.

Comment: Can you copy paste your code in a JSFiddle so I can see what I can do ?

Comment: Ok thanks, i'm sorry but it's quite awful so i put it on pastebin to make it less ugly   :  http://pastebin.com/AmJHzLn7

Comment: Can you make some screenshots of what you see on screen ?

Comment: So maybe you have to specify a `height` on the slider with an `overflow:hidden` and set `width: 100%;` to the images in the slider

Answer (score 0):

Try this **[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/mt9m25v2/2/)**:

```
#slider img{
display: inline-block;   
border:none;
//display:none;
height: 100%; width: 100%;}

#slider { 
display: inline-block;
background:#fff url(loading.gif) no-repeat 50% 50%;
margin-left: 10%;
margin-right: 15%;
transform: translate3d(0,0,0);
box-shadow: 0px 1px 5px #999999;}
```